# Visibility of AysncStorage data to users

Tags: asyncstorage

I prefer to encrypt the data that I store on LocalStorage as it can be seen on browsers by end users of my web application. For example, on Chrome, LocalStorage data can be seen under Developer Tools -> Application -> Storage -> Local Storage.

What about AsyncStorage on mobile apps? Can this data be seen too by end users of the mobile app?